# Wingate Proxy replacement

Tags: proxy

We have an isolated network, net02. Some devices in this network need internet access(http). I currently use the Wingate application but it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Wingate is installed on a Windows server with 2 network cards, net01 which accesses the internet and net02 which is isolated. Wingate serves as a gateway between these two networks. On the devices that need to access the internet I have configured Wingate as a Proxy.

Do you know of any other simple apps that can do the same? I am more familiar with Windows but if I have no choice it can be in Linux.

Comment: I have the same question. I have been using Wingate for well over a decade and have noticed the same with little to no updates to the software. Their VPN add-on is last updated in 2009 and didn't work for us. Although it does serve its purpose and once was a top-notch software, it is very outdated and development has all but stopped. If someone finds a good alternative, please post!